# COPY TO statement in postgres outputting double backslashes

Tags: postgresql

I would like to output a string with backslashes that is enclosed in dollar quotes to a file in postgres.  For example, with the following query:

```
COPY (select $$a\x5cb\x5cc$$ ) to $$c:\test.txt$$;
```

I would expect the contents of the file to be

`a\b\c`

consistent with the documentation from Postgres suggesting that these string literals should be, well, literals:

> Notice that inside the dollar-quoted string, single quotes can be used without needing to be escaped. Indeed, no characters inside a dollar-quoted string are ever escaped: the string content is always written literally. **Backslashes are not special**, and neither are dollar signs, unless they are part of a sequence matching the opening tag.

However, to my surprise, the contents of this file are instead

`a\\b\\c`

Why is this the case?  How can I output a literal string to a file without using single

Comment: Backslash is special in the COPY text format, that's why it's doubled. COPY doesn't have a verbatim format, it's either csv or text with custom backslash sequences.

Comment: Surprisingly, I was not able to make the custom backslash sequences work either, which I should edit into the question.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how you got the string into COPY TO.  The output of COPY TO is defined on its own terms.

Read the "Text Format" section of [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) for the command you are using.

The output of COPY TO is not inside the dollar quotes strings, so the rules of those strings does not matter.

You can use `with (format csv);` option to COPY.  It will consider a different set of characters to be special, and will escape those special characters in a different way.  It will not double the backslashes, but might do something else you don't like instead.

Comment: I also attempted to use the \xhh syntax without success.

Comment: Since `\\` are not special inside dollar quoted strings, why would \xhh do anything special when inside dollar quotes strings?